# how to get the id using e.target

Tags: jquery

Hi I would like to use jquery to get the element id. But I get the undefined. Would someone told me how to fix it. Thanks in advance.

There is my code:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="vehicle1" name="vehicle1" value="Bike" onchange="checkItem(this);">
function checkItem(e) {
    var senderId = $(e.target).attr('id');              
     alert(senderId);  
}
```

If I use the below code, I can get the id but I would like to try jquery

```
var sender = (e && e.target) || (window.event && window.event.srcElement);
var senderId = sender.id;
```

Comment: You call `checkItem` with the element itself `checkItem(this);`, so the parameter `e` is not an event. There would be no `e.target`

Comment: Are you just looking for `e.id` in this case?  If you want to know what properties `e` has, log it to the console and observe what's there.

Comment: Stop using HTML inline `on*` handlers to start with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you just need a id you can use below code.

```js
//via jquery
function checkItem(e) {
    var senderId = $(e)[0].id;            
     alert(senderId);  
}
//via javascript
function checkItem(e) {
    var senderId = e.id;             
     alert(senderId);  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" id="vehicle1" name="vehicle1" value="Bike" onchange="checkItem(this);">
```

Comment: `var senderId = $(e)[0].id;` I wouldn't call that "via jquery" as it's using jQuery for absolutely zero reason. Wrapping the element then *immediately unwrapping it*. It's the same as if you said "I arrived by car" and what you actually did was went into a car, immediately left, then walked the rest of the way.

Comment: @VLAZ this is already representing a currentObject I don't know why we are going for jQuery.